# Prediction of the ratio

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, statistics

Suppose there is a jar with *100* marbles of which *80 are red* and *20 are blue* (80/20 ratio or **p<sub>red</sub> = 0.8**).
Each day *20 randomly chosen marbles* out of those original 100 are replaced by *20 new marbles* of which only *9 are red* and *11 are blue* (45/55 ratio or **p<sub>red new</sub> = 0.45**). So, for example 20 marbles are taken out of the jar. 16 are red, 4 blue. They get replaced with 9 red and 11 blue marbles. Now 73 marbles in the jar are red and 27 are blue.

I want to plot it as a sequence of expected values like so:

| Day | Expected number of red marbles |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 80 |
| 1 | 73 |
| 2 | 67 |
| 3 | 64 |
| ... | ... |
| n | 45 |

How to calculate the expected value for each day using a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each day you remove $\frac15$ of the marbles, so on average you expect to remove $\frac15$ of the red marbles.  Then you add another $9$ red marbles.  So if $e_n$ is the expected number of red marbles on day $n$, then
$$e_{n+1}=\frac45e_n+9\ ,\qquad e_0=80\ .$$
This can be solved by standard methods to give
$$e_n=35\Bigl(\frac45\Bigr)^n+45\ .$$